# FS RX2A Pro Receiver Not Working

Tags: hardware, troubleshooting

I'm building a drone for the first time following the Prusa tutorial (https://blog.prusaprinters.org/how-to-build-a-3d-printed-micro-drone/) but couldn't get the RC receiver to work. I got my receiver from here (https://banggood.app.link/f7SKbZC5I5) and I'm using the HGLRC XJB F413 board.

I've binded the receiver to the controller and soldered the positive and negative wires to the board. Left the remaining two wires (one yellow, one light brown) cause I wasn't sure which they are (one is SBUS and one is PPM but not sure which is which). I first connected the board to Betaflight and set it to PPM. Tried connecting one of the wires and was able to get readings from controller. Then I set Betaflight to SBUS and connected the other wire but couldn't get any readings out of it. I tried a few more times with both PPM and SBUS but it just stopped working. After a few trials the receiver stopped beeping and light up when I connected the battery and its temperature became very high within a few seconds.

I initially thought I either shorted something when I was figuring out which wire's which or the receiver was defective so I purchased another one but the exact thing happened again. So I was wondering if anyone knows what's going on here and if there's anything I can do to get it to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that specific receiver is not working you may want to try a different receiver that will work with the same transmitter

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that you tried SBUS, but that receiver only supports PPM and IBUS (not SBUS).  Try setting your flight controller to use IBUS.  As for the RX getting hot - I'm not sure about that.  The photo on banggood shows that it takes VCC, but be careful.  The description details indicate that it only accepts 3.3 - 5 volts for voltage.  If your using anything more than a 1S Lipo, you will certainly fry the RX unless you have it soldered to either a 3.3V or 5V pad.

Here is the protocol and voltage information from Banggood.

**Signal output: IBUS, PPM**

**Power input: 3.3-5V**

Comment: I don't know why it never occured to me to check the product specs. Yes I used a 2S and have probably both of my receivers. Will also try IBUS instead. Thanks for pointing it out! I'll update back here when I try a new receiver.